# Markup tags in product descriptions

Tags: magento

I'm trying to use markup tags to link to info pages within the "description" attribute of a product.  However, it's not giving me a clean URL path when the description is printed to the page.

Trying:

```
<a href="{{store url="contacts"}}">Contact Us</a>
```

does not give the expected url.  I've confirmed i'm doing this outside of WYSIWYG mode too.

When the text is rendered is returned to the browser as this html:

```
<a href="{{store url=" contacts"}}"="">Contact Us</a>
```

A resulting click on the link then ends up as:

```
http://example.com/prod-category/my-product/%7B%7Bstore%20url=
```

From what I can tell the markup tags aren't designed to be used in this way.  Is it possible to extend it so it could work?  Otherwise I guess I need to include the actual URL in the description?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can´t use the double-curly** syntax because the attributes value is not being processed by magento´s template filter, which does the magic. You can use them e.g. in CMS or email Templates out of the box.